# Odoo V11 restapi - TypeError(repr(o) + “ is not JSON serializable”)

Tags: json, python-3.x, rest, odoo-11

Am using odoo v11 integrating with restapi though working fine in CRUD operations when getting report data with error

**file.py**

```
 def generate_report(self, xml_id, ids):
    self_reports = {}
    self_reports = {'result': False, 'state': False, 'exception': None}
    try:
        result, format = request.env.ref(xml_id).sudo().render_qweb_pdf([ids])
        if not result:
            tb = sys.exc_info()
            self_reports['exception'] = odoo.exceptions.DeferredException('RML is not available at specified location or not enough data to print!', tb)
        self_reports['result'] = result
        self_reports['format'] = format
        self_reports['state'] = True
        self_reports.update({'id': ids})
    except Exception as exception:
        _logger.exception('Exception: %s\n', exception)
        if hasattr(exception, 'name') and hasattr(exception, 'value'):
            self_reports['exception'] = odoo.exceptions.DeferredException(tools.ustr(exception.name), tools.ustr(exception.value))
        else:
            tb = sys.exc_info()
            self_reports['exception'] = odoo.exceptions.DeferredException(tools.exception_to_unicode(exception), tb)
        self_reports['state'] = True

    exc = self_reports['exception']
    if exc:
        raise UserError('%s: %s' % (exc.message, exc.traceback))
    if self_reports['state']:    
        if tools.config['reportgz']:
            import zlib
            res2 = zlib.compress(result)
        else:
            if isinstance(result, str):
                res2 = result.encode('latin1', 'replace')
            else:
                res2 = result
        if res2:
            self_reports['result'] = base64.encodestring(res2)
    return self_reports

def get_response(self, status_code, status, data=None):
    """Returns Response Object with given status code and status"""
    response = Response()
    response.status = status
    if data:
        response.data = isinstance(data, str) and data or json.dumps(data)
    response.status_code = status_code
    return response
```

this is data format

```
list: [{'exception': None, 'state': True, 'id': 3, 'format': 'pdf', 'result': 
b'SlZCRVJpMHhMak1LTVNBd0lHOWlhZ284UEFvdlZIbHdaU0F2VUdGblpYTUtMME52ZFc1MElERUtM\nMHRwWkh
NZ1d5QXpJREFnVWlCZApDajQrQ21WdVpHOWlhZ295SURBZ2IySnFDanc4Q2k5UWNtOWtk\nV05sY2lBb1VIbFFSR
Vl5S1FvK1BncGxibVJ2WW1vS015QXdJRzlpCmFnbzhQQW92VW1WemIzVnlZ\nMlZ6SURVZ01DQlNDaTlCYm01dmR
ITWdNVGdnTUNCU0NpOVFZWEpsYm5RZ01TQXdJRklLTDFSNWNH\nVWcKTDFCaFoyVUtMMDFsWkdsaFFtOTRJR  
nNnTUNBd0lEWXhNaUEzT1RJZ1hRb3ZRMjl1ZEdWdWRI\nTWdNVGtnTUNCU0NqNCtDbVZ1Wkc5aQphZ28wSUR        
BZ2IySnFDanc4Q2k5VWVYQmxJQzlEWVhSaGJH\nOW5DaTlRWVdkbGN5QXhJREFnVWdvK1BncGxibVJ2WW1vS05T
QXdJRzlpCmFnbzhQQW92UTI5c2Iz\nSlRjR0ZqWlNBOFBBb3ZRMU53SUM5RVpYWnBZMlZTUjBJS0wwTlRjR2NnTD   
BSbGRtbGpaVWR5WVhr\nS0wxQkQKVTNBZ05pQXdJRklLUGo0S0wwVjRkRWRUZEdGMFpTQThQQW92UjFOaElEY
2dNQ0JTQ2o0\nK0NpOUdiMjUwSUR3OENpOUdPQ0E0SURBZwpVZ292UmpjZ01UTWdNQ0JTQ2o0K0NpOVFZWFI ...
```

Error Traceback:

```
 File "E:\Odoo\odoo11\addons\restapi\controllers\main.py", line 343, in call_report
return self.get_response(200, str(200), {'report': datas})
 File "E:\Odoo\odoo11\addons\restapi\controllers\main.py", line 135, in get_response
response.data = isinstance(data, str) and data or json.dumps(data)
 File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python35\lib\json\__init__.py", line 230, in dumps
return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
 File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python35\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
 File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python35\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
 File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python35\lib\json\encoder.py", line 180, in default
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

I need the pdf report in binary data in api response , getting error in response data. Please anyone help me to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

This is because you might you forget to **import json** lib. In your header declare like `import json` this might help you to solve your error.

Comment: You have to pass return object in list fun. Because in py2.7 direct we are getting dict but in py3.x we are getting list of dict so you have to return your response via list. You can refer this : http://markhneedham.com/blog/2017/03/19/python-3-typeerror-object-type-dict_values-not-json-serializable/

Comment: b'SlZCRVJpMHhMak1LTVNBd0lHOWlhZ284UEFvdlZIbHdaU0F2VUdGblpYTUtMME52ZFc1MElERUtM\nMHRwWkh ... ==\n' is not JSON serializable

Comment: I got it by json.dumps(data, default=str)